# How to add elements to an array in Bash on each iteration of a loop?

Tags: arrays, bash

I have this `depends` file in my `$PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
k=0
for i in "$@"
do
  DP[k]="nodejs-$i"
  k=$((k+1))
done

echo $DP
```

I ran `depends js kd` and it returned:

```
nodejs-js
```

this surprised me as I thought that the result I would get would be:

```
nodejs-js nodejs-kd
```

as the loop was meant to be adding new elements to the `DP` array of form `nodejs-$i` where `$i` is the input I provided to the `depends` script when I ran it. I have tried using this depends script instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
DP=()
for i in "$@"
do
  DP+=("nodejs-$i")
done

echo $DP
```

but it returned the exact same result, with the `js kd` inputs (i.e., the output was `nodejs-js`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your script is correctly adding elements into the array, check how to read the DP array below.

Give this a try:

```
#!/bin/bash
k=0
for i
do
  DP[k]="nodejs-$i"
  k=$((k+1))
done

printf "DP array size is %d\n" "${#DP[@]}"
printf "%s " "${DP[@]}"
printf "\n"
```

--edited-- Note that new applications are encouraged to use printf instead of echo.

*Funny =>* By default the **for** statement loops over the script's arguments.

The test:

```
$ ./depends js kd
DP array size is 2
nodejs-js nodejs-kd
```

Comment: It should be `"${DP[@]}"` - with the quotation marks - not `${DP[*]}`, in general.  The former preserves any internal whitespace, while the latter does not.  Also, `echo` is not deprecated.  If you are explicitly using `bash`, as here, its behavior is consistent.  When using unspecified varieties of `/bin/sh`, `echo` has inconsistencies not present with `printf` - but then, `printf` itself may not exist at all in such shells, so it's not really an improvement.

Comment: @MarkReed thx! array notation fixed! According to the [APPLICATION USAGE section of the POSIX standard for echo](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), the `printf` built-in command is a preferred replacement for `echo` .

Comment: That guideline is for POSIX.  The code given is explicitly for `#!/bin/bash`, which is already not POSIX compliant - its `echo` takes options, including `-n`.

Comment: It's actually simpler to use the `+=` operator to append to the array, rather than manually updating the index `k`. `DP+=( "nodejs-$i" )`. (Assuming you don't need to support `bash` 3.0 or earlier.)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that Bash treats `$DP` as if it was `${DP[0]}`.  You need

```
echo "${DP[@]}"
```